# Approximating derivative in C

Tags: c, function, derivative

Given a differentiable function f : [a,b] → R and x ∈ [a,b], the derivative f′(x) can be approximated by the different quotient
Φ(h):=(f(x+h)−f(x))/h for h>0.
Write a function double diff(double (*f)(double), double x, double h0, double tau), which computes the sequence Φ(hn), where hn := pow(2,−n)*h0 (n ∈ N), until
|Φ(hn) − Φ(hn+1)| ≤ τ if |Φ(hn)| ≤ τ, or |Φ(hn) − Φ(hn+1)| ≤ τ|Φ(hn)| else.
The function then returns the value Φ(hn) as an approximation of f′(x). Use assert to check whether τ,h0 > 0 holds. The function uses a suitable implementation of the object function double f(double x). Finally, write a main program which reads x, h0 and τ from the keyboard and prints the value of Φ(hn) to the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

double f(double x) {
  return x*x + 2;
}

double hn (double h0, int n){
    int hn;
    hn=(pow(2,-n)*h0);
    return hn;
}

double func (double h, double x){
    double func;
    func=(f(x+h)-f(x))/h;
    return func;
}

double diff(double (*f)(double), double x, double h0, double tau){
    int n=0;
    int c=0;
    if (fabs(func(h0,n))<=tau){
        while (fabs(func(h0,n)-func(h0,n+1))>=tau){
            n++;
        }
        return func(h0,n+1);
    }
    else{
        while (fabs(func(h0,c)-func(h0,c+1))>=tau*fabs(func(h0,c))){
            c++;
        }
        return func(h0, c+1);
     }
}

int main(void){
    double x;
    double h0;
    double tau;
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    scanf("%lf", &h0);
    scanf("%lf", &tau);
    printf("%f", diff(f, x, h0, tau));
}
```

I don`t understand what I`m doing wrong.

Comment: OK, *why* do you believe you are doing something wrong?

Comment: When I enter x, h0 and tau the program doesnt run the functions but lets me enter more digits :/

Comment: How are you entering them? In one line? Or separate? Hitting Enter in the end? Show your exact input

Comment: separately by hitting enter;

Comment: For example for x - 3 for h0 - 1 and for tau - 0.01 (Each in a new row) and when I hit enter again it lets me input more numbers

Comment: Can't reproduce this behavior.

Comment: annnna, Tip, use `printf("%g"....`  (g, not f) for more informative output.

Comment: Avoid re-using names.  Instead of `double func (double h, double x){ double func; ...`, use `double func (double h, double x){  double func_value;...`

Comment: annnna, post input used, output seen, output expected.

Comment: Some systems are finicky about the lack of a final `'\n'`.  `printf("%f", diff(f, x, h0, tau));` --> `printf("%f\n", diff(f, x, h0, tau));`

Comment: Are you [actually](https://godbolt.org/z/Wh3ddWvj9) entering negative values? Because it [works](https://godbolt.org/z/boMGs87zo) with positive values.

Comment: Thanks it seams to work now after implementing all of this !!

Answer (score 0):

Basically what happens is that you have created an infinite loop in the 'diff' function. In the second while-loop, you are testing for `fabs(func(h0,c)-func(h0,c+1))>=tau*fabs(func(h0,c))`. The first part of the expression is always either positive or zero (because of the fabs function). The problem is that this is not true for the second part of the inequality for certain values for tau. When tau is negative, then `tau*fabs(func(h0,c))` will always be either negative or zero. So the first part of the inequality is always positive (or zero), and the second part of the inequality is always negative (or zero). The expression in the while-loop is always true for negative values for tau and does not change during the program.